# How to display the result using search button and textbox to listview

Tags: vb6

I'm coding a search button to listview and display the result data only

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Dim itmx As ListItem
    Set itmx = Listview1.FindItem(Text3.Text, lvwText, , lvwPartial)

    If itmx Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "record not found", vbCritical
    Else
        Listview1.ListItems(itmx.Index).Selected = True
        Listview1.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

I expect the result will display only the data which I Search in textbox, the code above only highlighted the the row in listview.

Comment: This code will only select the first item that matches your search criteria. Are you looking to find multiple items? If so, you can specify an `Index` parameter in the `FindItem` method. You can use a `Do While Not itmx Is Nothing` loop and use `itmx.Index + 1` on every pass to set the next `Index` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will select multiple items in your ListView matching your search criteria and remove those that don't:

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Dim itmx As ListItem
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim iRecordsFound As Integer
    Dim fMultiSelect As Boolean

    ' Store state of ListView's MultiSelect property and set it to True
    fMultiSelect = ListView1.MultiSelect
    ListView1.MultiSelect = True

    ' Deselect any selected items
    For iIndex = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
        ListView1.ListItems.Item(iIndex).Selected = False
    Next

    ' Initialize variables
    iIndex = 1
    iRecordsFound = 0

    Do While iIndex > 0 And iIndex <= ListView1.ListItems.Count

        Set itmx = ListView1.FindItem(Text3.Text, lvwText, iIndex, lvwPartial)

        If itmx Is Nothing Then
            iIndex = 0
        Else
            itmx.Selected = True
            iIndex = itmx.Index + 1
            iRecordsFound = iRecordsFound + 1
        End If

    Loop

    ' Delete unselected items
    For iIndex = ListView1.ListItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Not ListView1.ListItems.Item(iIndex).Selected Then
            ListView1.ListItems.Remove iIndex
        End If
    Next

    If iRecordsFound = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No records found", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox iRecordsFound & " records found", vbInformation
    End If

    ' Restore state of ListView's MultiSelect property
    ListView1.MultiSelect = fMultiSelect

    ListView1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir good day,Thank you for ur reponse quickly to my problem, my point is that if i search  for example the ID 20191 it only display all the 20191 data stored in listview.

Comment: the code above this error when i search 3times " invalid property of value"

Comment: Is there other data that is not in the listview? I imagine you are populating your listview from a data file (database, text file, etc) so if you explain where the data is coming from we can help you retrieve the data that matches your search criteria.

Comment: this line is error  - Set itmx = Listview1.FindItem(Text3.Text, lvwText, iLastIndex, lvwPartial), when i put that 20192 record it appears invalid property of value

Comment: Can you update your Question with your current code? I've tried the code and it is working fine. While you are editing the Question, please provide a better description of what you are trying to do with the result of your search.

Comment: I want to display what I only search in textbox to listview not all the data

Comment: I revised the code to remove listitems that don't match the search criteria.

Comment: sorry for the late response sir I tried this code but its remove all data it shows only 1 data result in my listview, the other duplicate datas is removed

Comment: Make sure `ListView1.MultiSelect = True`. You can set that in the ListView property window.

Comment: sir it's working but there's an error pop up , invalid property value when I searched for the last data in list view

Comment: Made a few changes:
1. Loop has new condition to check if iIndex is greater than ListItems.Count
2. Setting MutliSelect to True during the operation and restoring original state afterwards.
3. Deselecting any selected items before operation.